# Powershell Query AD to export emails of all users in .txt file?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to write a PS script that exports a .csv for all users that are specified in a separate .txt file. So, for instance, I could create a text file that has

```
Timmy Turner
Silly Sally
```

Then, when the script is ran, it searches AD for those two users and exports a CSV with their first name, last name, and email address.

I originally got hung up a bit on how the "Get-ADUser" filter worked, but I produced something semi-usable. However, what I've come up with just asks who you are searching for and then uses that. I think it would be much easier to just have it reference a pre-made text file, especially when searching for a large number of users. Or, there may be an even easier way to do this that I am not thinking of. Here is what I currently have:

```
$SamAc = Read-Host 'What is the first and last name of the person you would like to search for?'
$filter = "sAmAccountname -eq ""$SamAc"""

Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress | select FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\PS_ADQuery\Email_Addresses.csv"
```

I feel like the "Get-Content" cmdlet is close to what I am looking for, but I can't seem to get it to function correctly. I may be going in the totally wrong direction, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It turns out I even had the AD properties totally wrong. Take my comments with a grain of salt since I may not fully understand the processes behind each line of code, but this does exactly what I was looking to do.

```
#creates a $users variable for each username listed in the users.txt file. the ForEach
#command allows you to loop through each item in the users.txt array. the scriptblock 
#nested into the ForEach command queries each username for specific properties.
$users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content C:\Scripts\PS_ADQuery\users.txt)) {

    Get-AdUser $user -Properties GivenName,sn,mail

}

#takes the $users variable defined by the ForEach command and exports listed properties 
#to a csv format.     
 $users |
 Select-Object GivenName,sn,mail |
 Export-CSV -Path C:\Scripts\PS_ADQuery\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```